# [UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer contentOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11b9c7410

Tags: ios

crash in [UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer contentOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11b9c7410, how to resolve it

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:-[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer contentOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11b9c7410
Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation ___exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) 236
1 libobjc.A.dylib bool method_lists_contains_any<method_list_t*>(method_list_t, method_list_t , objc_selector , unsigned long) (in libobjc.A.dylib) 979
2 CoreFoundation -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation) 139
3 CoreFoundation ____forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation) 1439
4 CoreFoundation ___forwarding_prep_0___ (in CoreFoundation) 91
5 GeoServices 0x000000018c7b4448 0x18b7e2000 + 16589896
6 UIKitCore -[UITableView setContentOffset:] (in UIKitCore) 87
7 UIKitCore -[UIScrollView _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] (in UIKitCore) 99
8 UIKitCore -[UIScrollView setFrame:] (in UIKitCore) 547
9 UIKitCore -[UITableView setFrame:] (in UIKitCore) 211
10 UIKitCore -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] (in UIKitCore) 771
11 UIKitCore -[UIScrollView(_UIOldConstraintBasedLayoutSupport) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] (in UIKitCore) 51
12 UIKitCore ___46-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]_block_invoke (in UIKitCore) 119
13 CoreFoundation ___NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation) 15
14 CoreFoundation -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation) 459
15 UIKitCore -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] (in UIKitCore) 199
16 UIKitCore -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] (in UIKitCore) 591
17 BaiduBoxApp -[BBACommentListViewController createUIView] (in BaiduBoxApp) (BBACommentListViewController.m:541) 15
18 BaiduBoxApp -[BBACommentListViewController viewDidLoad] (in BaiduBoxApp) (BBACommentListViewController.m:282) 15
19 UIKitCore -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] (in UIKitCore) 103
20 UIKitCore -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] (in UIKitCore) 1019
21 UIKitCore -[UIViewController view] (in UIKitCore) 27
``
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some relevant code to your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.